# How to test wifi connection using given ssid and password and returns result of whether given ssid and password is correct or not

Tags: java, android

I want to test wifi connection through android app to check whether entered wifi ssid and password is correct or not. How i can check whether the given ssid and password is correct?

Comment: by trying to connect th that network. If it connects - then ssid/password is correct

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko If it connects but there's no Internet access, can you still tell?

Comment: yes, you don't need to check internet access, just check the wifi connection state

Comment: once you connect the wifi you can get its states and all details like ssid etc.if its connected then its correct else its not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we do in our app:

1. We ensure that the wifi is enabled
2. We create a WifiConfiguration with the ssid and pw (note that WifiConfiguration.SSID and WifiConfiguration.preSharedKey are surrounded in quotes so that if the ssid is example and the pw is password then `WifiConfiguration.SSID = "\"example\""` and `WifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"password\""`
3. We add the WifiConfiguration to the WifiManager (`WifiManager.addNetwork(WifiConfiguration)`)
4. We check the return value (which is a networkId) if it is -1 then the operation was not successful
5. We tell the WifiManager fo enable the networkId from the previous step and attempt to connect (`WifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)`)
6. We check if the negotiation with this WifiConfiguration was successful. This step has some ugly code, and I would love to get some other ideas, but it works:

   ```
   private static boolean checkWifiNegotiation(WifiManager wifiManager, int netId) {
       boolean startedHandshake = false;
       boolean successful = false;

       for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(300);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           SupplicantState currentState = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState();
           if (!startedHandshake && currentState.equals(SupplicantState.FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE)) {
               startedHandshake = true;
           } else if (startedHandshake) {
               if (currentState.equals(SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED)) {
                   break;
               } else if (currentState.equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED)) {
                   successful = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
       }

       // no matter what happened above, if COMPLETED then we have the correct pw
       if (!successful && wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState().equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED)) {
           successful = true;
       }

       return successful;
   }
   ```

Comment: How we can check the password for given ssid is correct or incorrect?

Comment: We assume that if the wifi is on and the network is added and enabled then if the negotiation is not successful it must be a bad pw

Comment: When we get the netId as -1?. And because of netId = -1 the the statement       
                 wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);                                                         is not evaluating.

Comment: statements after wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);  in checkWifiNegotiation() function are not execute.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: If you get -1 then you were not able to add the wificonfiguration. There are many reasons why this might be happening. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016918/android-wifimanager-addnetwork-returns-1)

Comment: Just curious, did you figure this out?

Comment: Thanks for your response above code is now working for me.

Comment: But we need to reset the network setting to return successful result, without reset it reurns false value for correct credentials why there is need of reset network settings.