# Please let me know if there is a standard android feature to install Wi-Fi settings with one tap

Tags: android, authentication, android-wifi

I have a question regarding a standard android feature.

https://osu.globalreachtech.com/onlinesignup/5156794

We are currently working on a demo site that allows **one-tap installation of Wi-Fi settings** as shown in the URL above.

The installation has been proven using the **Passpoint (Hotspot 2.0)** functionality.

We would like to know if there is a one-tap installation of **standard EAP-TTLS** Wi-Fi settings like Passpoint as a standard feature.

After checking the source code and the relevant parts of the public information, we believe that such a feature is not likely to exist.

Please let me know if you have knowledge of such a feature.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into `WifiManager#addNetworkSuggestions`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905956/is-it-possible-to-add-a-network-configuration-on-android-q

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have confirmed it.
I would like to know if it is possible to realize this as a standard feature of android, not as an app, etc., but it seems probably difficult.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "standard feature of Android". If you are asking whether there is a way to add the network suggestions from a web page, then no, there are no ways to do that from a web page that I know of.

Comment: As you said, I was aware of "whether there is a way to add network suggestions from a web page". Thank you.